# Issues with Wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed wordpress on two websites on 2 different domain.

1. xyz.com
2. 123.com

Both website has installed the same version of wordpress.

Now, I've moved all the files of `xyz.com` to `123.com` and changed the URL from `123.com` to `xyz.com` from wordpress settings.

But there is still showing base URL as `123.com`.

How can i replace the URL permanently to `xyz.com`?

Thanks

Comment: did you change in database too ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps you can follow:

1) open phpmyadmin or any other mysql client.

2) open `wp_options` table.

3) search for `siteurl` & `home` and change the url there.

4) dump sql file and search replace any occurrences of that url to new url, and then upload new changes. (make sure you have the backup of sql dump).

You are done..

Comment: Checked it  and found that it's already the same URL ! XYZ.com in database.

Comment: it shows this : in files  > Theme URI: http://www.123.com
Author URI: http://www.123.com

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention about exporting your wordpress database from xyz.com to 123.com. you should have search for xyz.com and replace it with 123.com before importing database to 123.com

like datas in wp_options

siteurl,home should also be replace with 123.com and some other datas inside the database that contains xyz.com should be changed to 123.com.

Steps how to manually Change all the links

1. Export your 123.com database using phpmyadmin
2. Open sublime or any text editor you have and open the sql file you have exported in step 1.
3. In sublime you can click `Find` then select `Replace`[image]
4. search for 123.com and replace with xyz.com
5. Click Replace All then save the sql file
6. Go to xyz.com's phpmyadmin and import the sql file you saved in step five.

**You could also use [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) Plugin**

**Note**

**`Always Be Careful and always make your database backup.`**

Comment: Yes i did this and replaced the URLs and now i have to import again back to the desired URL's phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes import it in your 123 phpmyadmin. make your 123 database is empty before you import the new sql file.

Comment: Okay, I want XYZ so i will import to it's phpmyadmin.

Comment: I have update my answer its a kind of reverse instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Here you'll find everything you need:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Like Sagar Guhe allready said, you can change the URL in your database.
Database name and authentification are set up in the config file in the root directory of wordpress in case you need to change that.

Answer (score 1):

- Take export of the database 123.com in dreamweaver , sublime, notepad++ or any text editor.
- In the .sql file find "siteurl" and the url which looks like `123.com` replace it with the desired url that is `xyz.com` do **find and replace**
- Then upload the newly updated database and change the configuration of wordpress files of `xyz.com` located in the root folder named as `wp-config.php`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and will  let you know